# How do I subtract 90, 180 days from today's date which includes all entries in between in excel?

Tags: excel

I'm trying to create my own spreadsheet for a logbook.  I need to show recency going back 90 days, 182 days and 365 days.  I want it to report how many hours I have accumulated in a certain machine which in this case is a helicopter.  I already have a tab that I enter the data on and a second tab that totals all of my entries broken down by aircraft type, number and types of landings, conditions of flight (day, night, night vision, in clouds, in simulator etc.) there are about 20 columns.  I am looking for a formula or part of a formula that will report only the items that fall within the period.  Thanks in advance for any information that ya'll might be able to provide.

I have researched this question many times in the past and still not found the help I need.  I apologize if I have duplicated the question.   Sean

This question could apply to anyone trying to determine a trend or needs to show recency for equipment use to project when an overhaul is due.

Answer (score 0):

Not 100% clear on your requirements so given you a few steps which may get you there, if not I'll need a little more clarity on what you need.

Assuming your data sheet has a date column you could do something like:

```
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&now()-90,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&now())
```

Where you data is in a sheet named 'Data' with the date in column A and the data you want to sum in column B. As you can probably tell the -90 is the days offset for todays date so the above would show total for the last 90 days, changing it as per below will give you the last 180 days, 365 days and between 30 to 90 days ago (to show range...) respectively.

```
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&now()-180,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&now())
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&now()-365,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&now())
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&now()-60,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&now()-30)
```

If you wanted it relevant to a certain date rather than using now() you could put the date you want in cell A1 of the sheet your summary is in and use:

```
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&$A$1-90,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&$A$1)
```

Reading through your question again are you saying you want to break it down by things like aircraft type etc? In which case you would need something like a table in your summary sheet, lets say in column A you have aircraft type and in your data tab you have date in column A, hours (or whatever you are summing) in column B and the type of aircraft in column C. In cell B1 of your summary:

```
=SUMIFS('Data'!$B:$B,'Data'!$A:$A,">"&now()-90,'Data'!$A:$A,"<"&now(),'Data'!$C:$C,$A2)
```

You could then copy this formula down and it will sum the relevant rows. If there was not an occurrence for a certain aircraft in the period you would get a 0, if you wanted a list of just the ones you logged hours for you would need to use pivot table probably, which is a whole new discussion (and not one of my strong ones unfortunately).

Hope this solves it, if not I'd need to see the spreadsheet.